# AWS: cloud-init failed

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a custom centos AMI on which i installed aws-cfn-bootstrap from https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest.amzn1.noarch.rpm.

After running cloudformation script,cloud-init is stuck for that instance.
I tried to look into cloud-init.log. I couldn't able to debug the issue.
and I have no idea how to debug this. Help needed, I am currently stuck here. Below are some errors from log. Help me in solving this.

Do I need to change cloud-init.cfg ??

```
2017-10-10 13:12:26,172 - util.py[DEBUG]: Running command ['mount', '-o', 'ro,sync', '-t', 'iso9660', '/dev/xvda', '/tmp/tmptIJHi2'] with allowed return codes [0] (shell=False, capture=True)
2017-10-10 13:12:26,188 - util.py[DEBUG]: Failed mount of '/dev/xvda' as 'iso9660': Unexpected error while running command.
Command: ['mount', '-o', 'ro,sync', '-t', 'iso9660', '/dev/xvda', '/tmp/tmptIJHi2']
Exit code: 32
Reason: -
Stdout: -

2017-10-10 13:12:27,908 - util.py[DEBUG]: Failed mount of '/dev/xvda' as 'iso9660': Unexpected error while running command.
Command: ['mount', '-o', 'ro,sync', '-t', 'iso9660', '/dev/xvda', '/tmp/tmpJcAGOG']
Exit code: 32
Reason: -
Stdout: -

2017-10-11 04:05:42,847 - util.py[WARNING]: Failed running /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001 [1]
2017-10-11 04:05:42,847 - util.py[DEBUG]: Failed running /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001 [1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 802, in runparts
    subp(prefix + [exe_path], capture=False)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cloudinit/util.py", line 1858, in subp
    cmd=args)
ProcessExecutionError: Unexpected error while running command.
Command: ['/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001']
Exit code: 1
Reason: -
Stdout: -
Stderr: -
```

BRs,
Kiran

Answer (score -1):

The problem of yours is the mount command.
Are you launch the instance using from existing server (using it's AMI)?
You can check by running the command on that server, and see if it is working or not.

I believe that your command is something like this.

```
mount -o ro,sync -t iso9660 /dev/xvda /tmp/tmptIJHi2
```

Comment: Cloudformation script is triggering cloudinit which is trying to setup something for cloudinit. yes, it is executing the similar command as you mentioned in the process.

Comment: Yes,  I know about that.  But I want you to make sure that your command is works first  before you put in the cloud init.  You can try in running instance first.  I have this kind of problem too sometimes.